# how to use variable in jstree data?

Tags: javascript

this is my code

```
var treedata = ['{ "id" : "ajson1", "parent" : "#", "text" : "Customer" }', 
   '{ "id" : "ajson2", "parent" : "ajson1", "text" : "Order number" }',
   '{ "id" : "ajson3", "parent" : "ajson1", "text" : "Date" }',      
   '{ "id" : "ajson4", "parent" : "#", "text" : "Company Name" }',
   '{ "id" : "ajson5", "parent" : "#", "text" : "Contact Name" }',
   '{ "id" : "ajson6", "parent" : "#", "text" : "Name1" }',
   '{ "id" : "ajson7", "parent" : "#", "text" : "Product number1" }'];

$('#data').jstree({
        'core' : {
            'data' : treedata 
        }
    });
```

but when i run it it do nothing but we i use this

```
$('#data').jstree({
        'core' : {
            'data' : {
                   ['{ "id" : "ajson1", "parent" : "#", "text" : "Customer" }', 
   '{ "id" : "ajson2", "parent" : "ajson1", "text" : "Order number" }',
   '{ "id" : "ajson3", "parent" : "ajson1", "text" : "Date" }',      
   '{ "id" : "ajson4", "parent" : "#", "text" : "Company Name" }',
   '{ "id" : "ajson5", "parent" : "#", "text" : "Contact Name" }',
   '{ "id" : "ajson6", "parent" : "#", "text" : "Name1" }',
   '{ "id" : "ajson7", "parent" : "#", "text" : "Product number1" }'];

}
        }
    });
```

it work
so how can i use variable in data ??

i wanted to run first code but it is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean that you want to use a variable for a property value?

If you just want to use the variable:

```js
let n = 42;

const obj = {
  'id': n
}
```

If you want to place the variable within a string, any of the following works:

```js
let name = 'Bob';

const obj = {
  'description1': `User, ${name}, is cool`,
  'description2': 'User, ' + name + ', is cool',
  'description3': 'User, '.concat(name, ', is cool')
};
```

Comment: okthanks it works